# Ghost voter in fourth election?

Tags: discussion, election

The Election page [here](https://stackoverflow.com/election/4) says:

> 139,718 voters were eligible, 87,022 visited the site during the election, 33,846 visited the election page, and **6,573** voted

However, both the result calculation pages ([OpaVote](http://www.opavote.org/results/967088/0) and the one by [Michael Mrozek](http://so.mrozekma.com/election4.html)) both list **6,574** valid votes.

Where's the extra vote coming from?

Comment: May be that ghost voter is [Community ♦](http://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community).

Comment: @hims056 I bet Community voted for me! ;)

Comment: @AndrewBarber, Congratulations to you, i am very happy to see you with Diamond.

Comment: Maybe someone voted with two accounts and they were merged immediately afterwards?

Comment: @toscho That seems most likely (or a user was outright deleted), as only 6,573 users are listed as having been awarded the Constituent badge for this election.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, inspecting the ballot file, there are 6574 lines of votes (besides, MichaelMrozek's page is just a formatted version of the raw OpenSTV output -- since the format/algorithm is by OpenSTV, I'd trust their data more). I doubt that any are invalid -- the election system tries to prevent that. This probably is a bug on SE's side.

However, there are 56 votes where a user has neglected to vote for their first (and/or second) choice, and have directly given their second/third choice. Going through them, it seems that they are all OK, considering that this counts as a valid vote (the preferences get shifted).

---

Toscho [makes a good point](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171606/ghost-voter-in-fourth-election/171609#comment508289_171606). The number of voters in an SE election is probably counted directly from the vote input (which is *later* converted to the BLT<sup>1</sup> file). A user merge/deletion may be the root of this.

<sup>1 Every time I think of this it makes me hungry</sup>

Comment: A whole file full of BLT goodness? Makes me hungry, too!

Comment: There probably should be a system in place to negate the vote once the user account is merged, since it shouldn't have been cast in the first place. OTOH, I doubt this is a problem on a wide enough scale to merit that much attention.

Comment: @Asad: Yeah. This _was_ a problem in a certain election (can't give details), but again, it wasn't such a large problem that the sockpuppetry influenced the outcome.